# Closest parent not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my html

```
<div test="dive" data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 test="h3">morning Snack <i></i></h3>
    <p>seI'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>

   <form>
       <input test="sd" class="checkclass"  name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="checkbox-mini-0">Completed This.</label>
   </form>

    </div>
```

below is javascript

```
$(".checkclass").click(function() {
    var tes = $(this).closest("div").attr("test");
    alert(tes);
});
```

I am trying to access div.h3.i ... but i cant access div itself :/ .please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9cQmJ/ . where i am wrong ?

Comment: The `test` attribute is on the `h3` element, not `div`.

Comment: Creating your own attributes is not recommended. Use `data-XXX` attributes.

Comment: @Barmar: It's on both.

Comment: Oops, must be going blind.

Comment: @barmar : its on both , i am trying to test.. i am not using any attribute in my project

Comment: your input HTML markup is invalid, input tags are self closing elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the html after DOM is loaded looks like this

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content" aria-hidden="false">
    <p>seI'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
    <form>
        <div class="ui-checkbox">
            <input test="sd" class="checkclass" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0"
            data-mini="true" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-mini-0" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true"
            data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-theme="c" data-mini="true"
            class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Completed This.</span>
                <span
                class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-on">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So you must use another kind of selector, try using attribute selector

```
var tes = $(this).closest("div[test]").attr("test");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cQmJ/2/)

Comment: hey anton that works . actually i am trying to access divs h3 hi ..please see this fiddle .can you help me out.

Comment: @Vishnu then you can use `.find` to find the h3 var `tes = $(this).closest("div[test]").find('h3').attr("test");` http://jsfiddle.net/9cQmJ/10/

Comment: can you tell how you where debugging the html after DOM is loaded ?any plugins ?

Comment: @Vishnu It's because of the jQuery Mobile plugin

Answer (score 1):

you need to find the `div` element with the `test` attribute (if you want the test attribute of the div element)

```
var tes = $(this).closest("div[test]").attr("test");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6EvFm/)

test attribute of the h3 element

```
var tes = $(this).closest("div[test]").find('h3').attr("test");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6LnmP/)

The problem is jQuery Mobile is adding other html structure required for the styling of the elements, which adds other `div` elements to the structure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the checkbox gets wrapped by a div, you can see that in the javascript console.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cQmJ/5/

```
$(".checkclass").click(function () {
    var test = $(this).closest("div").attr("test");
    console.log($(this).closest('div')); // div surrounding checkbox
    console.log($(this).closest('div[test]').attr('test')); // now it gets to the div you want
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the framework wraps the checkbox inside a `div` element and you end up looking at the wrong div. One workaround is to locate the closest div that contains a `h3` element; and grab the attribute:

```
$(this).closest("div:has(h3)").find("h3").attr("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var tes = $(this).closest("div[data-role='collapsible']").attr('test');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/9cQmJ/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Another div has been created to wrap the checkbox that you can't see, and that's the one your code is referencing.

```
$(this).closest('div').find('input').attr('test');
```

You can see this by adding a debugger and testing out what jQuery selector you need to get what you want like this.

```
$('.checkclass').click(function () {
  var tes = $(this).closest('div').attr('test');
  debugger;
  // At this point, if your console is open you can inspect tes
  // and see it's not what you want.  Type in $(this).closest('div') 
  // and you'll see it's referencing a div that was created automatically.

  // Try different selectors to find what you need.
});
```